How to use a generic function defined in Python?
I have a class and a corresponding factory function that holds some state in a closure (event_bus):
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Callable, Any

class EventBus:

    def subscribe(self):
        print("Subscribed")

    def publish(self):
        print("Published") 

T = TypeVar('T')

def create_property(event_bus: EventBus):
    class Property(Generic[T]):
        def __init__(self, validator: Callable[[T], bool]):
            self._validator = validator

        def __set_name__(self, obj: Any, name: str):
            self.name = name

        def __get__(self, obj: Any, type: Any) -> T:
            return obj.__dict__.get(self.name)

        def __set__(self, obj: Any, value: T):
            if not self._validator(value):
                raise ValueError("Invalid value")
            obj.__dict__[self.name] = value
            event_bus.publish()

    def property(validator: Callable[[T], bool] = lambda x: True) -> Property[T]:    
        return Property(validator)

    return property

Now this compiles, and the property function has the correct type: Callable[..., Property[T]]. Property can be used as a descriptor, but when I try to do so I get compiler errors:
property: Callable[..., Property[T]] = create_property(EventBus())   


class MyComponent:

    width = property() # Type of "width" is partially unknown
                       # Type of "width" is "Property[Unknown]
    height: int = property(lambda x: x > 0) # Expression of type "Property[Unknown]" is 
                                            # incompatible with declared type "int"

What am I doing wrong? How do I call the generic property function properly?

It's unclear. Are you asking on the type annotation? Or on the descriptor syntax? Your code contain several problems on both the type annotation and Python syntax unrelated on the type annotation, such as an undefined name error.

I'm trying to call the generic function, that's all I'm trying to do. I'm not sure what errors you are referring to apart from the ones in MyComponent.

What do you refer by 'the generic function'? Is it the property which is the return value of the create_property()? If you are asking on the type annotation, calling that function is completely unrelated to the type annotation. Anyway, the errors given by the type checker are clear. For example, for the first error, you didn't annotated the type of the width. You should move the definition of the Property class to the outside the create_property() and do like this, width: Property[int] = property().

Also just run your code by yourself. It will throw a NameError: name 'Property' is not defined

it is property (a function), not Property (a class). Check the source code again please.

The type hint is only there for illustrational purposes, so that it can be easily understood in the question.

You're not getting the point of the whole thing. The class uses the event_bus stored in the closure. I can't move it out of the function, in fact that's the whole point of the function itself. Aparat from all of these, what you're saying is unrelated to the problem at hand: how can I call a function that has a generic type parameter? How can I pass it? I tried inference (the reason why there is no type next to width), and passing a lambda that fixes the type of T (also didn't help)

You don't listen. I already said calling the property() function(specifying input arguments) is completely unrelated to the type annotation. Calling the function entirely depends on the function signature. The Generic class is designed only for supporting the type annotation. Also, as I said before, if you want to use a type checker on the width property, you need to move the Property class. If you don't want it, just don't use the type checker on it. It's your choice.

then I don't understand what you're saying. how can i explicitly pass the generic type parameter to a generic function in python? can I even do this? how can calling a generic function be unrelated to the generics in said function?

You can't specify the type parameters when you call a generic function. There's no reason or meaning for doing that. See the examples in the reference. You annotate type parameters when you define a function, and you call if without any annotation. A type checker will compare the type information of the arguments it inferred with the type information you annotated.

That inference doesn't work in my case. I come from other statically typed languages where this is the norm, so the way it works in python is alien to me.
